# ISerializable and inheritance, proper usage, CA2236

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, serialization, multiple-inheritance

I have a question regarding the correct implementation of ISerializable in the inherited class.

I had two classes, `AbstractBaseClass` and its implementation `BaseClass`. After the implementation of the `FinalClass` which derives from the `BaseClass` I'm getting the CA warning:

> CA2236    Call base class methods on ISerializable types  Method
>   'FinalClass.FinalClass(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)' should be
>   modified to call its base class implementation.

What I do not understand is why should I call the base class if the extracted `info.GetString("FileName")` and `info.GetString("Password")` are enough to create the instance of the `FinalClass`?

**Questions:**

1) Could someone please explain it to me?

2) Do I have any design problem if I leave it as is and just supress the warning?

Thanks

The simplified code sample is:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass : ISerializable
{
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue ...
        //...
    }

    protected AbstractBaseClass() {  }
    protected AbstractBaseClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info.GetInt32("Version") >= 1)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}

public class BaseClass : AbstractBaseClass, ISerializable
{
    public BaseClass() : base() { }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        info.AddValue ...
    }

    protected BaseClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        if (info.GetInt32("Version") >= 1)
        {
            Connection = new MyConnection();
        }
    }
}

public class FinalClass : BaseClass
{
    public string FileName { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }

    public FinalClass(string fileName, string password)
        : base()
    {
        FileName = fileName;
        Password = password;
    }

    protected FinalClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : this(info.GetString("FileName"), info.GetString("Password")) { }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        info.AddValue("FileName", FileName);
        info.AddValue("Password", Password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, in general, that would be sound advice. Should you ever change something in the base implementation, calling base would ensure that everything will keep working.

The compiler doesn't have the same knowledge as you. *You* know it's not necessary to call base, the compiler doesn't. The compiler *does* know that it's not illegal what you're doing, so it just emits a warning, telling you that there's some code that *might* require your attention (and warnings always should get your attention).

If this is *really* what you want, suppress the warning, but I personally would call the base constructor, just like the compiler suggests.

What you are doing now is not wrong *perse*. It's perfectly valid C# code, but the compiler decided to issue a warning because it "knows" (for simplicity's sake) about how `ISerializable` in combination with a serialization constructor is usually implemented.

Let's say in a next iteration `BaseClass` adds some property of its own, the Foo property, and assume that we want that property (de-)serialized. You would probably implement the necessary code for deserialization in the BaseClass(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext) constructor

```
public class BaseClass : AbstractBaseClass, ISerializable
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    protected BaseClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        // ...
        Foo = info.GetInt32("Foo");
        // ...
  }
}
```

In your current setup, when deserializing `FinalClass`, the Foo property of BaseClass would not be deserialized, since you decided to call the `this(string fileName, string password)` constructor, instead of `base(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)` constructor. And *that's* the scenario that this warning is all about. The setup is not future proof, and any addition to either `AbstractBaseClass` or `BaseClass` in the future that should also be deserialized in the constructor will in your current implementation **not** be deserialized.

So yes, you could say that the current implementation is a design mistake, although I would probably more likely call it a wrong implementation of the design.

Comment: The `FinalClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` calls `FinalClass(string fileName, string password)` which is calling the `base()`. So that is actually what the warning means, isn't it?

Comment: The warning is telling you that the serialization constructor FinalClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) does not call BaseClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context). That's the pattern it expects (since it is recommended), but does not find.

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite clear if I do have a problem or not. Does the base class need SerializationInfo and StreamingContext as well? Or it is ok to call the other constructor with extracted parameters? Is it ok to call the other base() from the other constructor as I do or do I need to call exactly `: base(info, context)` ?

Comment: @VladL: I'll update the answer with an example to (hopefully) make it more clear.

Comment: @VladL: Updated the answer, hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: Thanks but I just can't imagine **why** it might be needed to deserialize the base class? I can instanse the FinalClass like `new FinalClass(fileName, password);`? This call must initialize the base class as well, right? Or it is just usefull to recover the object state of the base class?

Comment: Because the full state of FinalClass *includes the state of BaseClass*. That's what inheritance does. Why would you want to only (de)serialize part of hierarchy!?